# How can I get a user(who is the current login) points from database Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to show just the points from the current user logged with doctrine and symfony2. I have a User and a table Points with user_id.
I need to show just the user logged. With this code, i'm showing all the points from the table.

Here is my controller

```
public function indexAction()
{   
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('AtividadeBundle:Points')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your controller:

```
$id= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
$entities = $em->getRepository('AtividadeBundle:Points')->findBy(array('user'=>$id));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$id= $this->getUser()->getId();//more simple and short way to get the current user
$entities = $em->getRepository('AtividadeBundle:Points')->findBy(array('user'=>$id));
```